# awk command: how to tell it to distinguish between space and tab delimiter

Tags: linux, awk, printf

I used this command, `awk '{print $1}' "$line"`, to get a column of data from a file that looks like this:(underscores represent tab as a delimiter, example is a three-column data)

```
Joe Jonas_____8_____45  
Cersei Lann_____4_____23  
Bo Tox_____6_____28  
Mis Ter Yo_____7_____89
```

When I run the command, say to get the first column, the output, however, showed it like this:

```
Joe  
Cersei  
Bo  
Mis
```

How can I make the command to ignore the spaces within the data of the first column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the field separator (-F) to tab(s):

```
$ awk -F$'\t*' '{gsub(/ /,"_",$1); print $1,$2}' test2.in
Joe_Jonas 8
Cersei_Lann 4
Bo_Tox 6
Mis_Ter_Yo 7
```

EDIT: Use `gsub` on first column to replace space with underscore.

Comment: I would like to ask, since even if i do this, my data is messed up because of the presence of space. How can I replace it with underscore after using awk?

Comment: You don't need to use the `$'\t'` bashism when using awk with -v or -F. Awk understands `'\t'` as meaning a literal tab character when provided as an argument to those options.

Comment: @DalePin wrt `my data is messed up...` you might want to post a new question to describe your problem with spaces as there's no reason for spaces to mess up anything.